# Disable GTM on the fly

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-protection

When a user clicks "I don't want you track me", I need to disable all trackers that mentioned in Google Tag Manager (as google analytics does using 'ga-disable-ua-xxxxx-y'). The problem is that I don't have these trackingIds.

I tried with ga.getAll(), but no trackers are still there until a Youtube tag fires, but it's too late for me.

https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/opt-out-of-google-analytics-tracking/, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/smtj53n4SFs both work, but I can't ask every customer to do this on their site (all GTM containers belong to customers). GTM Id is input by customers in our admin module.

So, basically I need just to disable all trackers from GTM without changes on GTM directly for this.

Comment: Maybe, there is something like window['ga-disable-*'], but seems no..

Comment: I have borrowed www.gov.uk's method of dealing with this (see https://www.gov.uk/help/cookies), which is to link to https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout. Not perfect but it does let people opt out.

Comment: I am not sure what does this approach mean. Set up the extension in a browser?

Comment: This gives them the instructions to install specific Google software within their browser that has the effect of disabling Google Analytics. That means you don't have to do anything within your own code.

Comment: As a manager I want to make my site GDPR compliant. If I went your suggestion I would then recommend just disabling cooking for the site in a browser.

Comment: Problem with that is that it would mess up /all/ cookies for the site, not just GA. It's up to you how far you are prepared to go with this, obviously. I must admit I assumed that what was considered ok for the UK government website would be ok for mine!